# Cmake: How can i build TDLib source code with OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, cmake, tdlib

I'm trying to build a tdlib using this instruction: https://tdlib.github.io/td/build.html?language=JavaScript.

Programming language: JavaScript
Operating system: Linux (Node.js)
Linux distro: Alpine

The build instructions for the node.js say: Note that for Node.js ≥ 17 you must build TDLib with OpenSSL 3.0.*, for Node.js ≥ 10 with OpenSSL 1.1.*, and for Node.js < 10 with OpenSSL 1.0.*, so you may need to modify the following commands to install a proper OpenSSL version.

I've never dealt with C++ or cmake before and don't quite understand how to do it.

I tried to find something like flags or variables in the documentation (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-env-variables.7.html) containing the substring SSL, but I couldn't find anything. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is a **question** exactly? Do you ask about how to install OpenSSL from sources (instead of using `apt`)? Or have you already have custom installation of OpenSSL and wanted to tell tdlib to use it?

Comment: @Tsyvarev custom installation? It's something like libssl-dev? I think i can install that library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev and yes, i wanted to tell tdlib to use it.

Comment: Your comments explain a little... "i wanted to tell tdlib to use it" - You want to tell tdlib to use **what**? Do you have OpenSSL installed as `libssl-dev` package (via `apt`)? In that case OpenSSL should be found without your hints.